# ThreeJS PointLight doesn't work after change camera position

Tags: three.js

I'm very new to Three, so this is very basic question.
HERE is my code, just generate 3 objects are sun, earth and mars.
The below is work find util I change camera position and sun size, earth size and mars size to bigger then I realize the PointLight is not working any more.

WORKING CODE:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
import { GUI } from 'dat.gui';

// Import static files
import stars from './static/stars.jpg';
import sunTexture from './static/sun.jpg';
import earthTexture from './static/earth.jpg';
import marsTexture from './static/mars.jpg';

// Create a SCENE
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const cubeTextureLoader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
scene.background = cubeTextureLoader.load([
  stars,
  stars,
  stars,
  stars,
  stars,
  stars,
]);

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  45, // field of view
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000,
);

camera.position.set(0, 30, 50);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

const gui = new GUI();
const options = {
  displayAxis: false,
  sunRotate: true,
};
gui.add(options, 'sunRotate');
gui.add(options, 'displayAxis');

const sunGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1);
attribute
const sunMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xFFFFFF,
  map: textureLoader.load(sunTexture),
});

const sun = new THREE.Mesh(sunGeometry, sunMaterial);

scene.add(sun);

const createPlanet = (size, positions, texture) => {
  // Do the same with Sun
  const planetGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(size);
  const planetMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    map: textureLoader.load(texture),
  });
  const planet = new THREE.Mesh(planetGeometry, planetMaterial);
  planet.position.x = positions[0] || 0;
  planet.position.y = positions[1] || 0;
  planet.position.z = positions[2] || 0;

  const sunStar = new THREE.Object3D();
  sunStar.add(planet);
  scene.add(sunStar);

  return { planet, sunStar };
};

const earth = createPlanet(0.3, [3], earthTexture);
const mars = createPlanet(0.5, [10, 0, 5], marsTexture);

const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 10, 300);
scene.add(pointLight);
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x333333, 2);
scene.add(ambientLight);
const pointLightHelper = new THREE.PointLightHelper(pointLight, 300);
scene.add(pointLightHelper);

new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(100);
scene.add(axesHelper);

const animate = () => {
  // Refresh app frame follow screen refresh frame
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  if (options.sunRotate) {
    sun.rotateY(0.001);
  }

  earth.planet.rotateY(0.03);
  earth.sunStar.rotateY(0.005);

  mars.planet.rotateY(0.019);
  mars.sunStar.rotateY(0.001);

  if (options.displayAxis) {
    scene.add(axesHelper);
  } else {
    scene.remove(axesHelper);
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
});

animate();
```

NOT WORKING CODE:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
import { GUI } from 'dat.gui';

// Import static files
import stars from './static/stars.jpg';
import sunTexture from './static/sun.jpg';
import earthTexture from './static/earth.jpg';
import marsTexture from './static/mars.jpg';

// Create a SCENE
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const cubeTextureLoader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
scene.background = cubeTextureLoader.load([
  stars,
  stars,
  stars,
  stars,
  stars,
  stars,
]);

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  45, // field of view
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000,
);

camera.position.set(-90, 140, 140);


const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();


const gui = new GUI();
const options = {
  displayAxis: false,
  sunRotate: true,
};
gui.add(options, 'sunRotate');
gui.add(options, 'displayAxis');

const sunGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(16);

const sunMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: textureLoader.load(sunTexture),
});

const sun = new THREE.Mesh(sunGeometry, sunMaterial);

scene.add(sun);

const createPlanet = (size, positions, texture) => {
  // Do the same with Sun
  const planetGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(size);
  const planetMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    map: textureLoader.load(texture),
  });
  const planet = new THREE.Mesh(planetGeometry, planetMaterial);
  planet.position.x = positions[0] || 0;
  planet.position.y = positions[1] || 0;
  planet.position.z = positions[2] || 0;

  const sunStar = new THREE.Object3D();
  sunStar.add(planet);
  scene.add(sunStar);

  return { planet, sunStar };
};

const earth = createPlanet(6, [63], earthTexture);
const mars = createPlanet(0.5, [10, 0, 5], marsTexture);

const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 1, 300, 2);
scene.add(pointLight);
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x333333, 2);
scene.add(ambientLight);
const pointLightHelper = new THREE.PointLightHelper(pointLight, 300);
scene.add(pointLightHelper);


new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(100);
scene.add(axesHelper);

const animate = () => {
  // Refresh app frame follow screen refresh frame
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  if (options.sunRotate) {
    sun.rotateY(0.001);
  }

  earth.planet.rotateY(0.03);
  earth.sunStar.rotateY(0.005);

  mars.planet.rotateY(0.019);
  mars.sunStar.rotateY(0.001);

  if (options.displayAxis) {
    scene.add(axesHelper);
  } else {
    scene.remove(axesHelper);
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
});

animate();
```

Hope receive the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why PointLight is not working is because its intensity is set to 1. If you change its value to 8000, it works:
`const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 8000 /* Notice here */, 300, 2);`